# How can I query the weekly records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see the records whose invoice date is only this week (Monday to Sunday). When I run the query for the next weeks, I want to place a restriction where I can only see the records for that week. Thank you in advance for your help.

Select ‘Amount’=InvoiceAmount,‘date’=InvoiceDate from Invoice where InvoiceDate>=.....

Comment: Please provide info on your DB / table structure, some consumable sample data and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Firstdayofcurrentweek DATETIME, @Lastdayofcurrentweek DATETIME
-- First Day of Current Week
SELECT @Firstdayofcurrentweek = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
-- Last Day of Current Week
SELECT @Lastdayofcurrentweek = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 6)
```

Your query :

```
SELECT [Amount] = InvoiceAmount,
       [date] = InvoiceDate 
FROM Invoice 
WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Firstdayofcurrentweek AND @Lastdayofcurrentweek
```

Comment: Don't use "smart" quotes in code; they don't work.

Comment: Also *{literal string} = expression* for aliasing is deprecated (since at least [2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15)) and should **not** be used. I would, however, also suggest completely avoiding literal strings for column aliases as it can be quite confusing. Instead use the T-SQL or ANSI-SQL delimit identifiers when you need to (brackets (`[]`), and double quotes (`"`) respectively).